# redux state updating incorrectly

Tags: reactjs, redux

I was trying to study the redux flow with an example. But got stuck upon in between. Here is the [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/4tCh6dl2UXj56GAdzj2d?p=preview) link for the same.

```
function combineReducers(currentState, action) {

  var nextState = Object.assign({}, currentState);

    /*On load placeholder details for all thumbnails*/
    var placeholder = {
        urlPath: "http://placehold.it/640x480",
        header: "PLACEHOLDER",
        description: "Description text for the above image"
    };
    if (currentState === undefined) {       
        nextState = placeholder;
        return nextState;
    }
  //Problem here i guess
  nextState = {
      animals : animalReducer(nextState.animals, action),    
      architecture : architectureReducer(nextState.architecture, action)    
  }

  return nextState;
}
```

The application loads with an initial state of setting all media elements to a placeholder. ( That is working )
On individual button click, it was supposed to fetch details of each category and only populate those media element.

**Problem:**

> When i click the Go button, both 1 and 2 elements is updating
>   together. Ideally i was expecting to get only Animal details on
>   clicking element 1, Architecture details on element 2, Nature on 3 and
>   People on 4.

I have not implemented 3 and 4 as i am sure if this works, then it will be more of just adding additional actions and reducers for each piece of state.

I think the problem lies in, rootReducer.js line 19, or index.js, Line 34 or 37, but not sure how to proceed! Any pointers will be of great help! Ive already pulled off a hell lot of hairs on my head today!

> **PS:** I know doing in jquery is kind of crud, but just for learning purpose.!

Advanced thanks for the helpers!
Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://plnkr.co/edit/WDyQHy5tftm2EX6AFQ9j?p=preview

```
var defaultState = {
  animals: Object.assign({}, placeholder),
  architecture: Object.assign({}, placeholder)
};

if (currentState === undefined) {       
    nextState = defaultState;
    return nextState;
}
nextState = {
  animals : animalReducer(nextState.animals, action),    
  architecture : architectureReducer(nextState.architecture, action)    
}
```

1. The reducers were not returning the original state in the default case
2. Default state format and the combined reducer state format were different

Comment: thanks for the working plunkr! that did helped indeed

Answer (score 1):

In both `animalReducer` and `architectureReducer` you need to return `currentState` in the `default:` case, otherwise you'd `null` the other part each time something changes. `nextState` is not defined in `default:`.

A reducer by default does not do anything to the state, *it has to keep it unchanged*. Only if there is a matching action, it should create a new object with the updated state. The thing here is that you do not adher to that rule and by chance null the state by default.

Comment: @donmatrin, thanks for the explanation! That as helpful .. the updated plunk above too helped! Thanks a lot for the quick turn around,